# R- programming - Error in seq.default(a, length = max(0, b - a - 1)) : length must be non-negative number

Tags: r

I tried running the code below.

```
library(sfsmisc)
set.seed(307)
y  <- rnorm(200)
h2 <- 0.3773427

t   <- seq(-3.317670,  2.963407, length.out=500)
fit <- density(y, bw=h2, n=1024, kernel="epanechnikov")

integrate.xy(fit$x, fit$y, min(fit$x), t[407])
```

However, i received the following message:

> "Error in seq.default(a, length = max(0, b - a - 1)) : 
>     length must be non-negative number".

I am not sure what's wrong.

I do not encounter any problem when i use t[406] or t[408] as follow:

```
integrate.xy(fit$x, fit$y, min(fit$x), t[406])
integrate.xy(fit$x, fit$y, min(fit$x), t[408])
```

Does anyone know what's the problem and how to fix it? Appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: This question is off topic.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is not very informative, but if you look at the code of the `integrate.xy(x,fx,a,b)` function, you can see that this error appears when no match is found for `b` in the interpolated distribution of x, given the tolerance factor. As you don't specify a tolerance factor, the default value is used, which is `xtol=2e-08`.
Using `xtol`, the `integrate.xy` function defines a `dig` parameter which equals `dig=round(-log10(xtol))`. This parameter is used to define the number of digits after the decimal point that are taken into account when matching parameter `b` with the interpolated distribution of x.
If you change `xtol`, you can see that the function only returns the error message for values of `xtol~<3.16228e-7`, corresponding to the threshold between a `dig` value of 6 and a `dig` value of 7. Which means that when taking 6 digits after the decimal point, you find a match for `b` within the interpolated distribution of x but when taking 7, you don't.
You can resolve your issue by changing the `xtol` parameter to a value of 3.16228e-7 or higher.

```
integrate.xy(fit$x, fit$y, min(fit$x), t[407],xtol=3.16228e-7)
[1] 0.9565527
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your suggestion. I tried the method and no longer see the error for the above simulation with set.seed(307). However, the error still occur when I tried to run the following code:

```
for (i in 1:2000) {
print(i)
set.seed(i)
y  <- rnorm(200)
h2 <- 0.3773427

t   <- seq(-3.317670,  2.963407, length.out=500)
fit <- density(y, bw=h2, n=1024, kernel="epanechnikov")

integrate.xy(fit$x, fit$y, min(fit$x), t[407],xtol=3.16228e-7)
}
```

The same occur when i use xtol=4.16228e-6.

Is there a way to resolve the issue so that I won't run into this problem?